# rsyncing git project folder

Tags: linux, git, rsync

I need to rsync a git project folder and I'm using the follow rsync flags       *-r -a -v -u -W* but when I run *git status* on the *destination* folder it does not match with *git status* on the source (I get modified/deleted files that were not actually touched).

Why is this happening? And how to make it work as intended?

Comment: "Work as intended"?  Well, rsync is not an intended way of sharing git repos, so...

Comment: Cannot you use `git fetch` to synchronize repositories?  is it a bare repository?  What do you mean with _as intended_?  what do you indend?

Comment: [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is the correct way to sync Git repositories. Or [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) if you run it at the destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **rsync** manual:

```
-u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
```

So it may skip files...

### Use git

Anyway, there is no need for rsync when you have the source dir versioned.

Clone the folder

```
cd /my/destination
git clone /my/source/repo
```

Sync the folder

```
cd /my/destination/repo
git fetch
```

Comment: `git pull` is more _branch_ oriented and for the user commodity.  If you want to synch, just do a `git fetch` (no need to update local branches if the repositories are _bare_)

Comment: the clone/fetch version seems to work but is there any way to get untracked files as well?

Comment: @user1233963 No, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The usual `rsync` command I use is

```
rsync --archive --delete --verbose src-dir/ dst-dir/
```

This makes `dst-dir` an exact mirror of `src-dir`. This will pick up everything, including your `.git` subdir and untracked files.